# How to detect changes to a copied object in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using `angular.copy` to clone an object so that I can detect changes to the object like so:

```js
var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.obj = {
    id: 1,
    str: "Hello World"
  };
  $scope.init = function() {
    $scope.objCopy = angular.copy($scope.obj);
  }
  $scope.hasChanges = false;
  $scope.change = function () {
    $scope.hasChanges = !($scope.obj == $scope.objCopy);
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="MyApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl" ng-init="init()">
      <input type="text" ng-model="objCopy.str" ng-change="change()" />
      <pre>obj = {{ obj }}</pre>
      <pre>objCopy = {{ objCopy }}</pre>
      <pre>hasChanges? {{ hasChanges }}</pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that although when I add characters to the string of text, the change is detected, if I edit the string back to its original text, the `hasChanges` variable still shows as `true`. I would like it to become `false` since the strings are equal. Are they not?

Comment: if you just check `str` wouldn't it be suffient? you could also JSON.stringify(obj) and check for equality

Comment: Use angular.equals(obj1, obj2) instead of obj1 == obj2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use angular equals

```js
var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.obj = {
    id: 1,
    str: "Hello World"
  };
  $scope.init = function() {
    $scope.objCopy = angular.copy($scope.obj);
  }
  $scope.hasChanges = false;
  $scope.change = function () {
    $scope.hasChanges = !angular.equals($scope.obj, $scope.objCopy);
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="MyApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl" ng-init="init()">
      <input type="text" ng-model="objCopy.str" ng-change="change()" />
      <pre>obj = {{ obj }}</pre>
      <pre>objCopy = {{ objCopy }}</pre>
      <pre>hasChanges? {{ hasChanges }}</pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**I think you should use angular.equals instead of using a reference equality:**

[https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.equals](http://Why%20aren't%20you%20using%20angular.equals?%20https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.equals)

Instead of:

```
$scope.hasChanges = !($scope.obj == $scope.objCopy);
```

replace it with:

```
$scope.hasChanges = !angular.equals($scope.obj, $scope.objCopy);
```

**Please try the following code:**

```js
var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.obj = {
    id: 1,
    str: "Hello World"
  };
  $scope.init = function() {
    $scope.objCopy = angular.copy($scope.obj);
  }
  $scope.hasChanges = false;
  $scope.change = function () {
    $scope.hasChanges = !angular.equals($scope.obj, $scope.objCopy);
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="MyApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl" ng-init="init()">
      <input type="text" ng-model="objCopy.str" ng-change="change()" />
      <pre>obj = {{ obj }}</pre>
      <pre>objCopy = {{ objCopy }}</pre>
      <pre>hasChanges? {{ hasChanges }}</pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also -> JSON.stringify($scope.obj) === JSON.stringify($scope.objCopy), although angular.equals is a better and safer option.

Comment: Of course that would work. I prefer angular.equals because it is more explicit, and we don't have to parse 2 objects as string in order to do a simple comparison.

Comment: Right on.  I just put it up there so that anyone who uses the 'equals' atleast looks up the advantages of it over this method :)